# Haml - how do I force tag attributes to use double quotes only AND how do I order tag attributes the way I want?

Tags: html, haml, staticmatic

I use staticmatic for templates I use later with PHP. There is an odd situation where some tag attributes have single quotes, while some have double quotation marks. I would like all of them to have double quotes exclusively (not that it matters I guess, but I want them like that!)

For example, haml code:

```
!!! XML
%html{html_attrs('hr-HR')}
  %head
    %title Some title
    %meta{'http-equiv' => 'Content-Type', :content => 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}/
    %meta{'name' => "description", :content => 'Some title - YO!'}/
    = stylesheets
    = javascripts('test', :other)
  %body
    = yield
```

produces following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<html lang='hr-HR' xml:lang='hr-HR' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
  <head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    <meta content='Some title - YO!' name='description' />
    <link href="stylesheets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="stylesheets/grid.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="stylesheets/text.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script language="javascript" src="javascripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" src="javascripts/other.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>some body stuff!</h1>
    utf test šđčćž ŠĐČĆŽ
  </body>
</html>
```

note that it doesn't matter if I use single quotes or double quotes in haml code, I always get the same output!

Also, it seems that haml->html output sorts tag attributes alphabetically, not the way I have ordered them in haml. I suspect this has something to do with ruby arrays, but I'm not sure since I don't/can't use Ruby apart from haml in staticmatic. How could I have them ordered the same as I have ordered them in ruby array in haml code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Haml::Template.options[:attr_wrapper] = '"'
```

Comment: where would I put that in staticmatic? configuration.rb in src/ under project made by staticmatic isn't it. Since I have little clue about ruby yet, I don't know where to put that configuration.

Comment: ok, I've monkey patched render.rb in staticmatic to include that option, it is all " now. Thanks!

Comment: For Rails3 I've put this line into `config/initializers/haml.rb`.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to pass template options when using haml as CLI... Oh, found it: `-q, --double-quote-attributes    Set attribute wrapper to double-quotes (default is single).`

Answer (score 2):

Haml does indeed order attributes alphabetically, and this is indeed a consequence of Ruby's parser. In the future, attributes may be ordered in document order as much as possible, but that's not likely to happen until Haml 2.2 or later.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible at all? I know it doesn't matter, the ordering of attributes, but it just doesn't feel right when looking at the code. I could prepare a helper and include that, but why would I use haml at all then, right?

Comment: The issue stems from how Haml compiles templates. It converts the templates first into Ruby code which runs to produce a string of HTML. It tries to parse the attribute hash before compiling (recently it's gotten better at this - it should be able to parse any attribute hash that doesn't include dynamic values), but if it can't, it inserts the hash as a literal Ruby hash in the compiled code. Since Ruby hashes don't preserve order (at least in Ruby 1.8), this means that the resulting attributes are in an undefined order. Then in order to make the output deterministic, Haml alphabetizes them.

Comment: Since Haml parses static attributes without dumping them to Ruby, it may be possible to output those in template order. The problem then becomes figuring out what to do with some static and some dynamic attributes. This is a solvable problem, and will probably be addressed eventually, but the next Haml version (2.2) is drawing close to release so it may be pushed off until version 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#options

> Haml understands various configuration options that affect its
>   performance and output.
>
> In Rails, options can be set by setting the `Haml::Template.options`
>   hash in an initializer:
>
> `# config/initializers/haml.rb`
>
> ```
> Haml::Template.options[:format] = :html5
> ```
>
> Outside Rails, you can set them by configuring them globally in `Haml::Options.defaults`:
>
> ```
> Haml::Options.defaults[:format] = :html5
> ```
>
> Finally, you can also set them by passing an options hash to [**Haml::Engine#initialize**][1]. For
>   the complete list of available options, please see [**Haml::Options**][2].
>
> [1]:
>   http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html#initialize-instance_method
>
> [2]: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html

Comment: Question is almost six years old :)

Comment: Yet i am new to this stuff, so actual for me. And can be for others.