# Rails - HAML element attributes are wrapped with single quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, haml

I have a Rails website and currently some of my tag attributes are generated with single quotes. I'm not sure if that will result to invalid markup but based validator.w3.org, it's valid and runs on HTML 5 doctype.

But I'm curious why my tags, specifically metatags are generated with single quotes. I generate the tags like this:

```
%meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}
```

and it generates this:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
```

It also uses single quotes for other meta tags like keywords and description metatags. I just want to try and make it consistent and use double quotes for everything if possible. Thanks.

Comment: It may be helpful [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967039/haml-how-do-i-force-tag-attributes-to-use-double-quotes-only-and-how-do-i-orde][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967039/haml-how-do-i-force-tag-attributes-to-use-double-quotes-only-and-how-do-i-orde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `tag` rails helper should keep you consistent:

```
tag 'meta', {:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}, true
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I used the solution suggested by pkubicki instead, adding in Haml::Template.options[:attr_wrapper] = '"' in config/initializers/haml.rb to make HAML generate double quotes for all attributes.